# How to execute a script at OOM with -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=

Tags: java, testing, error-handling, jvm, out-of-memory

I'm trying to set up a way to handle out of memory errors in my application.  So far, I've added the following options to my Gradle build file:

```
task appStartScripts(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    def tplName = 'startTemplate.sh'
    assert project.file(tplName).exists()
    defaultJvmOpts = ["-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError",
                      "-XX:HeapDumpPath=\$HOME/log/",
                      "-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./\$HOME/application/bin/restart.sh",
                      "-Xms64m", "-Xmx124m"]
    dependsOn shadowJar
    applicationName = 'start'
    defaultJvmOpts += ["-Dspring.profiles.active=ENV_VARIABLE"]
    classpath = startShadowScripts.classpath
    mainClassName = startShadowScripts.mainClassName
    outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'scriptsShadow')

    doLast {
        // IMPORTANT! needed to ensure HOME environment variable is expanded correctly
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('\\$HOME', '\'"$HOME"\'')
        unixScript.text = unixScript.text.replace('ENV_VARIABLE', '\'"$1"\'')
}
```

Where XX:OnOutOfMemoryError calls the restart script when the an out of memory error occurs.  In the restart.sh script itself, I have the following:

```
while true : do
    java -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -jar application.jar
    sleep 5
done

./start.sh
```

To kill the app, wait 5 seconds, and then call the start script in the same directory to restart the app.

To test this, I added an infinite loop to one of my get requests:

```
@GET
    @Timed
    @Path("/{ids}")
    public List<Profile> getProfileByID(@PathParam("ids") String ids) {

        boolean forever = true;

        try {
            logger.info("STARTED SERVICE: getProfileID with the following parameters: IDs = {}", ids);
            int[] array = idsStringToArray(ids);

            List<Profile> profileList = profileManager.getProfiles(array);

            List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            while (forever) {
                profileManager.getProfiles(array);
                myList.add(1000);
            }

            logger.info("COMPLETED SERVICE: getProfileID with the following parameters: Ids = {}", ids);
            return profileList;
        }
```

Where myList will continue to have more items added to it, consuming memory.

That said, I haven't been able to cause the error yet to trigger the script.  Is there anything else I can do?

Also, here is the result of the top command for the service:

```
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.4 us,  1.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32160180 total, 21291040 free,  4559124 used,  6310016 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  2097148 free,        0 used. 27127132 avail Mem
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
30504 user1  20   0 3778748 371724  18048 S   4.0  1.2   3:50.33 java
```

EDIT:
I just tried calling the OOM error directly in the code, but it just throw the exception and nothing else:

```
@GET
    @Timed
    @Path("/{ids}")
    public List<Profile> getProfileByID(@PathParam("ids") String ids) {

        boolean forever = true;

        try {
            logger.info("STARTED SERVICE: getProfileID with the following parameters: IDs = {}", ids);
            int[] array = idsStringToArray(ids);

            List<Profile> profileList = profileManager.getProfiles(array);

            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        }
```

Comment: `throw new OutOfMemoryError()`?

Comment: `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=./\$HOME/application/bin/restart.sh` I'm not sure I would expect whatever interprets and executes this at OOM time to do any environment variable substitution.  What happens if you don't escape the `$` and let the substitution happen at program launch time?

Comment: @JimGarrison gradle doesn't seem to handle $ well when generating the start scripts.  It ends up adding in multiple quotation marks and the JVM option would not work.  I have a replace method in the code to replace any instance of an escaped $ variable with the corrected variable, so it will work.  I'll add in the code in the question; I did not think it would be relevant.

Comment: @JonK I just tried that, and it does not seem to call the script at all.

Comment: @JimGarrison  I changed the path for the script to simply be ./restart.sh.  It seems to call it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to induce the error.  I did it by lowering the heap space even more than before:

```
"-Xms64m", "-Xmx124m",
```

and by having my get method generate a long with the long array, l:

```
@GET
@Timed
@Path("/{ids}")
public List<Profile> getProfileByID(@PathParam("ids") String ids) {

    boolean forever = true;

    try {
        logger.info("STARTED SERVICE: getProfileID with the following parameters: IDs = {}", ids);
        int[] array = idsStringToArray(ids);

        List<Profile> profileList = profileManager.getProfiles(array);

        long[] l = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```